# Graph using tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

How can see the graph, generated by TensorFlow using Tensorboard? Can anyone provide a simple example? I am very new to tensorflow. I am using python as well.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [`tf.summary.FileWriter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter) that writes your graph to a TensorBoard log. For instance:

```
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', graph=tf.get_default_graph())
summary_writer.flush()
```

And then launch `tensorboard` with the appropriate `--logdir` parameter.

Comment: and then open the browser at localhost:6006 and click on the graph tab :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create your computational graph

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(3)
b = tf.constant(4)

c = a+b

with tf.Session() as sess:
    File_Writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/home/theredcap/Documents/CS/Personal/Projects/Test/tensorflow/tensorboard/' , sess.graph )
    print(sess.run(c))
```

Here the `tf.summary.FileWriter(' path to store your logs')`writes the graph to the Tensorflow log

Then all you have to do is access the tensorboard with the mentioned log/graph that you just wrote with

```
tensorboard --logdir "path/to/logs"
```

Note: When I did

```
tensorboard --logdir = "the above mentioned path"
```

Nothing was displayed on my tensorboard

For more info

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/README.md